# Twitter-bootstrap javascript components not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

all in the title.
I cant get the javascript bootstrap components working.

```
<div id="example">Some element</div>

<script>
  $('#example').popover({
    title: 'A title!',
    content: 'Some content!',
    trigger: "hover"
  });
</script>
```

this is not working and not loading the popover.
same problem with:

```
$('#try').typeahead();
```

try.

loading sequence:

```
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
//or <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

i am not using data attributes for the sake of retrocompatibility.

Answer (score 5):

You need to wrap your Javascript in a page load event handler, like so:

```
<script>
  $(function()
  {
    $('#example').popover({
      title: 'A title!',
      content: 'Some content!',
      trigger: "hover"
    });
  });
</script>
```

See jQuery's [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) documentation.